# How to integrate Guice 2 into Wicket?

Tags: java, maven-2, dependency-injection, wicket, guice

I want to use Guice 2 with Wicket 1.4. There is a "wicket-guice" package, which uses Guice 1. Can someone give me an example how to configure Wicket to use Guice 2 for injection (with Maven).

As you can see blow, I've found a solution, but I wonder, if it would be better to use [Guice Servlets](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=ServletModule) and register the whole Wicket Application as a ServletFilter with Guice. But I think this would conflict with wickets object creation strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself I post the solution, which I found with the help of [AtomicGamer Dev Blog](http://www.atomicgamer.com/dev/2009/10/wicket-guice-2-0-warp-persist-2-0/).

Since wicket-guice supports only Guice 1, Guice needs to be excluded from the wicket-guice extension.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-guice</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.google.code.guice</groupId>
                                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

The actual integrations happens in the `init` method, which calls the `addComponentInstantiationListener` method.

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.apache.wicket.guice.GuiceComponentInjector;

public class NavigatorApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return Startpage.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
                Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WebAppModule());
                addComponentInstantiationListener(
                                new GuiceComponentInjector(this, injector));    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented a solution where wicket's configuration and startup are written purely in java code using Guice's ServletModule - no xml used for wicket at all.

All the details are described [here](http://headtoscreencollision.blogspot.com/2010/05/wicket-and-guice-alternate-route.html?x=stackoverflow) in a blog post I've written.

Full source (zip/svn) and a working example eclipse project are available for download as well (links are at the end of the post).

I think you'll find it great to once again forget about web.xml maintenance :)